# C++ linker error with static functions in .hpp-file

Tags: c++, function, static, linker, duplicates

I am using an open source library, which provides a .hpp-file with several static functions defined that looks like the code below.

When I include this file twice in my project I always get a linker error that complains about duplicate symbols. I am well aware of the fact that the functions are being defined twice, but I do not know how to resolve this. I have tried marking the functions extern or inline without success.

What is the best way to resolve this?

```
#ifndef OPENMVG_ROBUST_ESTIMATOR_ACRANSAC_H_
#define OPENMVG_ROBUST_ESTIMATOR_ACRANSAC_H_

#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

#include "openMVG/robust_estimation/rand_sampling.hpp"

namespace openMVG {
namespace robust{

static double logcombi(size_t k, size_t n)
{...}

...
```

**Edit**: I forgot to say that there are also template functions, which means that I cannot use .h and .cpp files. So that is why they used .hpp files. On this page ( http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ ) on the bottom it says that linkers should not produce errors in this case. I am using Xcode as an IDE with standard settings. Apparently there is something wrong here. The linker error looks like this:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN7openMVG6robust13UniformSampleEmmPSt6vectorImSaImEE in:
    /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SfM_OpenMVG-dgkssozpvorbpphdefdpurfpdaqv/Build/Intermediates/SfM_OpenMVG.build/Debug/SfM_incremental_unified.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SfMIncrementalEngine.o
    /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SfM_OpenMVG-dgkssozpvorbpphdefdpurfpdaqv/Build/Intermediates/SfM_OpenMVG.build/Debug/SfM_incremental_unified.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/computeMatches.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Resolution**: As it turns out the hpp-file I was referring to includes a file that defines a function with same name as one of the functions in the original file and that is what cause the linker error. I have no idea why this even worked in the first place when just including the .hpp file once.

Comment: When asking about compiler/linker errors, always include the actual error message in your question. Or, if there are too many of them (hundreds), the first few and the last few of the relevant ones.

Comment: I also had the same error before. If the `static` does not really mean a lot. Just removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you've done this but replace

```
static double logcombi(size_t k, size_t n)
```

with

```
inline double logcombi(size_t k, size_t n)
```

and *fully* recompile.

Comment: Upload the whole thing and ill take a look tomorrow. It's always possible to link c++ code; eventually

Comment: Thank you so much! You can get the hpp-file here: https://github.com/openMVG/openMVG/tree/master/src/openMVG/robust_estimation (the name is "robust_estimator_ACRansac.hpp". It includes one other file from the same directory.) Like I said, there is only a problem when I include the file in at least two other files.

Comment: I found the problem; please refer to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

To distribute your library in a header is a very strange thing. Since you have access to the source code, I'd just create the corresponding cpp file, copy & paste the code from the header to the cpp file, and then remove the bodies of the functions in the header.

I'd also remove the static functions from the header: it actually does not make much sense to have a static (private) function in the file in which you expect to find the exportable symbols (i.e., public functions).

Finally, are you sure there are only functions in that hpp file? If there were constants it would be equally problematic. In that case I'd keep the declaration with an extern in the header and would move the constant to the cpp file.

I know, it is a lot of work (well, not so much, actually), but it is also the only sensible way to arrange things.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I edited my question. As it turns out this cannot be done because of template functions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you implement such functions in the same place you declare them. This is the cause of error on double inclusion. So far, you have two alternatives:

1. Employ "inline" clause as recommended by **Bathsheba**. The problem is: "inline" is just a hint. Compiler may refuse your attempts of inlining the functions, even if "forceinline" asked. It seems, your case is not inline-compatible as it not helps you.
2. Split a function as usual .H + .CPP pair, so that client code would include the .H file and then link with a lib containing the .CPP

The fact you name your file as .HPP instead of .H does nothing with the way how compiler treats it. You can use any arbitrary extension for a file and then include it as a header. So, naming convention here is no more than good programming style (.H for C/C++ compatible headers, .HPP for C++ only).